# Connecting MySQL database from Windows

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I am using WAMPSERVER and I want to access MySQL database tables from windows command line. How can I do that? I'm very new to WampServer and and also with MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

The you will be prompted to type in your MySQL password.

But once there, it is clear you can not do something interesting since you are a beginner.
 Before trying to use the command line, learn how to use the interface of your WAMPServer to create a database. Use Google :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried mysql -u root -p but this showing 'mysql' is not recongized as an internal or external command, operable programe or batch file. I think mysql directory have to be put on environment variables. though I'm using WAMPSERVER I can't find exactly what directory to put on environment variables.

Comment: @Maktabun in that case, please specify your needs. Mention the version of Windows you are using, what you have tried and the errors you got. Read [how to read a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If MySQL is not in your PATH, first navigate to it: cd\ [ENTER] cd your/path/here (e.g. wamp/mysql/bin) [ENTER] and then repeat instructions above

Comment: Thanks now I can connect going C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/bin and running mysql -u root -p.

Comment: @Maktabun run: `cd C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/bin`

Comment: Note that in production, it's sensible to remove the 'root' user, but see elsewhere for more on database security

Comment: @Strawberry yes, I agree with you, especially that I studied security :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to use the wampmanager menus like so :-

left click the wampmanager icon and

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
```

This will launch the mysql.exe in a command windows and login to MySQL using the default 'root' userid and no password.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u adminusername -p
```

This works

Comment: currently Im using WAMPSERVER as root user. and I tried mysql -u root -p but this showing 'mysql' is not recongized as an internal or external command, operable programe or batch file. I think mysql directory have to be put on environment variables. though I'm using WAMPSERVER I can't find exactly what directory to put on environment variables.